# Use regex to add {} to a guid

Tags: regex

I have an xml file with a list of items:

```
<Items
  ID="1B884B58-0C47-451B-956E-44866A7F3F91"
  Name="Home"
  TemplateID="BD5B78E1-107E-4572-90DD-3F11F8A7534E"
  MasterID="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
  ParentID="70A77564-8D3F-459E-850F-FFC79CC97B38"
  Created="2009-07-17T12:18:57.247"
  Updated="2009-08-14T14:08:38.970"
/>
```

I need to run a regex that essentially looks at every GUID, and adds curly braces {} around the guid, e.g.

```
{B884B58-0C47-451B-956E-44866A7F3F91}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple acceptable formats for GUIDs, but sticking only with the one you have specified:

```
 /([0-9A-F]{8}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{12})/{$1}/g
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `[0-9A-F]{8}-(?:[0-9A-F]{4}-){3}[0-9A-F]{12}` with `{$0}`

OR

Replace `([0-9A-F]{8}-(?:[0-9A-F]{4}-){3}[0-9A-F]{12})` with `{$1}`